# Translate Enum Keys with i18n in Angular and bind to MatSelection

Tags: angular, enums, internationalization, translation, mat-select

I have an Enum like this

```
export enum LogEvent
{
    All = 0,
    Created = 1,
    Modified = 2,
    Delete = 3
}
```

I want to convert these enum keys with i18n translation and bind them to MatSelection.
The selected value should be the number.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Create Pipe transfrom like this with i18n:

   ```
    @Pipe({
        name: 'textLogEvent',
        pure: false 
    }) 
    export class LogEventPipe implements PipeTransform {
        constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }

    transform(value: Enums.LogEvent) {
        try {
            switch (+value) {
                case Enums.LogEvent.All:
                    return this.translate.instant('t-all');
                case Enums.LogEvent.Created:
                    return this.translate.instant('t-created');
                case Enums.LogEvent.Modified:
                    return this.translate.instant('t-modified');
                case Enums.LogEvent.Delete:
                    return this.translate.instant('t-delete');
                default:
                    return this.translate.instant('t-undefined');
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            return '';
        }
     } 
   }
   ```
2. In the mat selection you can use pipe text to load this enum value number like:

   ```
   {{ value | textLogEvent }}
   ```

Hope this help!